# using a for loop with xrange() on a multiple lists

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools

I have the below code which assign a number to each item from list1 depending on len(list1):

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
result = []

for i in xrange(0, len(list1)):
    result += (str(i+1), list1[i], )

new_result = list(izip(*[iter(result)]*2))
```

The result will print as following:

```
[("1", "a"), ("2", "b"), ("3", "c"), ("4", "d")]
```

If i have a multiple lists: list2, list3, list4

How can i apply it to this code?..

Comment: what is your desired result for multiple lists?

Comment: You don't need a loop at all: `result = [(str(i), x) for i, x in enumerate(list1, 1)]`. Replace `list1` with `list2`, etc as necessary.

Comment: @chepner it worked for me just fine, but if i take your approach and i wrote that line for 6 lists i have, isn't it considered repeated code that can be shorten and simplified with same approach but using a loop, just asking to improving my skills in code.

Comment: What ever you do, you can wrap in a function that takes `list1` or `list2` or whatever as an argument. The call to the function itself can be in the body of a loop that iterates over your lists.

Comment: @chepner, thx, refined my answer with `enumerate(list1, 1)`.

Comment: @chepner thanks for your help, your answer above hepled me a lot to understand, the for loop in below answer completed the task also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

```
lists = [   ["a", "b", "c", "d"],   # list1
            ["e", "f", "g", "h"]]   # list2

new_results = [[(str(idx), x) for idx, x in enumerate(l, 1)] for l in lists]
print(new_results)

# Output
[[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'd')], [('1', 'e'), ('2', 'f'), ('3', 'g'), ('4', 'h')]]
```